# regex: literal followed by one or more digit

Tags: regex

I would like to search for the literal US followed by a digit, that is repeated one or more times, followed by anything except a dash. For example, these should match:

```
US3.
US22?
US134!
```

while these don't

```
US5-
US66-
US789-
```

I have tried

```
r'US[0-9]+(?=[^-])'
```

but it also matches

```
'US6', 'US78'
```

How do I modify this?

Comment: What encompasses **anything** ?

Comment: This list [?, !, &, %, .]

Comment: So then it's not **anything**; it's the list that you provided. So specify that list in your post.

Comment: To build on Rahul's comment a little, `US78` is the literal US ("US") followed by a digit repeated one or more times ("7") followed by anything except a dash ("8"). Consequently I think maybe you need to be clearer about exactly you want from the regex - is that *anything* any punctation? Anything other than a number? etc.

Comment: Sorry, I get it. I think what I mean is, the literal could be followed by any number (without specifying its number of digits), as long as it's not followed by a dash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mention the list of characters after matching digits in a character class.

**Regex:** `US\d+[?!&%.]`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/o8G6hV/1/)**

Comment: Do you know the next charters will be in `[?!&%.]`?  OP suggested it could be anything that's not `-`.

Comment: @AaronN.Brock: OP mentioned it in comment.

Comment: Oh, I see now...  Well, with that bit of information, your answer is much more concise them mine.  Have an Upvote!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the absolute *best* way to go about doing this, but if you know that there is only one of these each line, you could just add a `$` to the positive lookahead like so:

```
US[0-9]+(?=[^-]$)
```

[**Regexr.com example**](https://regexr.com/3j22d)

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention the list of characters in character class that are allowed.

I have attached the screenshot of the output , you can verify it !

```
US[0-9]+[?!&%.]
```

[image: Output]